# Convert struct to map annotated with `firestore:"field_name"`

Tags: json, go, google-cloud-firestore

I have a struct -

```
type User struct {
    Uid      string `firestore:"uid"`
    FcmToken string `firestore:"fcmtoken"
}
```

How do I convert It to map using  `json.Marshal(user)` ,
I know it can be done when struct fields are annotated with `json:"fieldname"` but I don't know how to do the same when it is annotated with firestore, or is it even possible?

I have used the word annotation, which may not be what it is called, please correct me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A field tag can contain multiple key/value pairs. See the [struct tag documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#StructTag) for more details.

Edit the field tags to include whatever JSON configuration you want:

```
type User struct {
    Uid      string `firestore:"uid" json:"uid"`
    FcmToken string `firestore:"fcmtoken" json:"tid"`
}
```

It is not possible to make the JSON package use the firestore tags or vice versa.